# Bind a Silverlight TabControl to a Collection

Tags: silverlight, collections, binding, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I have a Collection of Model-objects in my ViewModel. I would like to be able to bind a TabControl to these and use a DataTemplate to extract the information from the Model-objects. When I try to do this I get the errormessage: Unable to cast object of type Model to object of type TabItem. After spending some time looking for a solution I found the following:

1. The Silverlight TabControl is
   broken. Use a combination of ListBox
   and ContentControl to mimic the
   behaviour of a TabControl. (Means
   that I have to skin the ListBox to
   look like a TabControl)
2. TabControl does not override
       PrepareContainerForItemOverride and
       the solution is to make a
       Converter. (Not so good because I
       then need to specify the type of the
       convertee in the Converter)

Anyone know any better solution?

XAML

```
<sdk:TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=MyControl}">
        <sdk:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </sdk:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </sdk:TabControl>
```

C#

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> Items { get; set; }

public ViewModel()

    Items = new ObservableCollection<Model>{
        new Model { Name = "1"},
        new Model { Name = "2"},
        new Model { Name = "3"},
        new Model { Name = "4"}
    };
}
```

[Suggested Converter](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/18256/165714.aspx):

```
public class TabConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<TabSource> source = value as List<TabSource>;
        if (source != null)
        {
            List<TabItem> result = new List<TabItem>();
            foreach (TabSource tab in source)
            {
                result.Add(new TabItem()
                {
                    Header = tab.Header,
                    Content = tab.Content
                });
            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've created the extended tab control which doesn't need a converter and works correctly with the ObservableCollection class. http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/silverlight-tabcontrol-with-data-binding/

Answer (score 2):

Create converter

```
public class SourceToTabItemsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                var source = (IEnumerable)value;
                if (source != null)
                {
                    var controlTemplate = (ControlTemplate)parameter;

                    var tabItems = new List<TabItem>();

                    foreach (object item in source)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = item.GetType().GetProperties();

                        //тут мы выбираем, то поле которое будет Header. Вы должны сами вводить это значение.
                        var propertyInfo = propertyInfos.First(x => x.Name == "name");

                        string headerText = null;
                        if (propertyInfo != null)
                        {
                            object propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
                            headerText = (propValue ?? string.Empty).ToString();
                        }

                        var tabItem = new TabItem
                                          {
                                              DataContext = item,
                                              Header = headerText,
                                              Content =
                                                  controlTemplate == null
                                                      ? item
                                                      : new ContentControl { Template = controlTemplate }
                                          };

                        tabItems.Add(tabItem);
                    }

                    return tabItems;
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ConvertBack method is not supported
        /// </summary>
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("ConvertBack method is not supported");
        }
```

Create ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTabItemContentTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

And binding convert, controltemplate

```
<controls:TabControl  x:Name="tabControl"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=tabControl, 
                              Path=DataContext, 
                              Converter={StaticResource ConverterCollectionToTabItems}, 
                              ConverterParameter={StaticResource MyTabItemContentTemplate}}">
        </controls:TabControl>
```

taken from the blog [binding-tabcontrol](https://simplecod.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/binding-tabcontrol-%D0%B2-silverlight-4-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3-%E2%84%961/)

Comment: Please summarize the content of your blog post here in English.  Also, you need to disclose that it's your own work when you link to your blog or any website, product, or project you're affiliated with.  See the [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) section of the FAQ.