# Value does not fall within the expected range in ObservableCollection<TabItems>

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, converters, tabcontrol

I have issue with tabcontrol control.

I'm using binding and converter to dynamically add items to tabcontrol.

When adding second tabitem get the following exception (see code below):
Value does not fall within the expected range

Its stacktrace:

в MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   в MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   в MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
   в System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   в System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
   в System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   в System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   в System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.set_Content(Object value)
   в SilverlightApplication1.Services.TabConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

MainPage xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="1024"
         d:DesignWidth="1280"
         xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1.Services">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:TabConverter x:Key="tabConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBoxItem Content="ViewA"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="ViewB"></ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <sdk:TabControl Grid.Column="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, Converter={StaticResource tabConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

MainPage code-behind:

```
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl {
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            viewModel.Tabs.Add(new TabItemModel() {
                Header = "New Tab",
                Content = new Grid()
            });

            // sdk:tabcontrol does not listen CollectionChanged of viewModel.Tabs.
            // thats why:
            viewModel.Tabs = viewModel.Tabs;
        } catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

Data model:

```
 public class TabItemModel {
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public UIElement Content { get; set; }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged {
    ObservableCollection<TabItemModel> tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItemModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<TabItemModel> Tabs {
        get { return tabs; }
        set { tabs = value; OnPropertyChanged(PropertyNames.Tabs); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string property) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    class PropertyNames {
        public const string Tabs = "Tabs";
    }
}
```

Tab converter:

```
public class TabConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        try {
            var object_data = value as ObservableCollection<TabItemModel>;
            var result = new List<TabItem>();
            foreach (var item in object_data) {
                result.Add(new TabItem() { 
                    Header = item.Header,
                    Content = item.Content // if comment this, everything works
                });
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace, e.Message, MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for posting working code, it was a simple copy paste for me :) I gave up after an hour, because it's just not working. Imo it is a flawed control. Take a look at @Sphinxxx answer, I think what you can use is in the link *Silverlight TabControl with data binding*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're keeping a `UIElement` in your data model.

In MVVM, this is a big no-no in itself, but the specific problem here is that as you add a second `TabItemModel` and the converter recreates all needed `TabItem`s, the *first* TabItemModel's content is placed on two TabItems at once for a split second. A single UI element can only have **one** parent.

The most "MVVM" solution here would be to keep UI elements out of your data model. Instead, just keep some piece of raw data in `TabItemModel.Content` and use `DataTemplate`s in your xaml to represent that data's UI.

If you *do* need to keep UI elements in your data model, I suggest you have a look at this tweaked TabControl which fixes the buggy Silverlight TabControl and doesn't require a converter to function properly: [Silverlight TabControl with data binding](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/silverlight-tabcontrol-with-data-binding/) (fetched from this SO post which discusses the same problem: [Bind a Silverlight TabControl to a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629888/bind-a-silverlight-tabcontrol-to-a-collection))

Comment: Was just checking this issue and found out that the ItemTemplate property is not working as one would expect for the Silverlight sdk `TabControl`.

Comment: @Silvermind: Yes, apparently that's right. The two links I posted in my answer address that exact issue (although I haven't tried vorrtex' tweaked TabControl myself).

Comment: I see that a problem with the `SelectedItem` was solved in an updated article from the same person: http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/silverlight-tabcontrol-with-scrolling-and-with-the-new-tab-button/ It looks like that's a good control for what the OP needs.

Comment: @DhavalPatel: Hope it helps. If it does, please consider accepting the answer :)